# How to downcast in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, downcast

How do I downcast in typescript?

```
const x: {a: number, b: number} = {a: 1, b: 2};

const y: {b: number}            = x;   //   upcast
const z: {a: number, b: number} = ???; // downcast
```

I can upcast `x` to `y`, but what needs to go in `???` to downcast `y` to `z`?

---

For comparison, C# would look like

```
AandB x = ...
A y = x;
B z = y as B;
```

Comment: `y as { a: number, b: number }` should work

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
type AandB = { a: number, b: number };

const x: AandB = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const y: {b: number} = x; // upcast
const z: { a: number, b: number } = y as AandB; // downcast
```